# Pandas: How to remove out of bounds timestamps while keeping null values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with a dataframe, and I want to remove dates before 1/1/1920, but keep null values. I begin by converting the column `DOB` to datetime like this:  `dob_df['DOB_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dob_df['DOB'])`

In my data, I occasionally come accross dates that triggers the out of bounds error like the following:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1076-04-04 00:00:00
```

I know that this can be solved by adding `errors='coerce'` to the `to_datetime` arugment, but that will also set the null values to NaT, and I want to differentiate them so I can include them in the data when I filter out the invalid dates.

Here's an example of the data:

```
PersonalID  DOB
48366   1076-04-04
50154   
50912   10/2/2019
50687   8/26/2019
50532   7/1/2019
50597   3/1/2019
```

I included one of the out-of-bound values and one of the nulls.

What's the best way to keep the null values and only coerce the out-of-bounds timestamps?

Comment: Please share a [mcve], including part of the relevant data. Depending on what those _null values_ are, there might be a rather straightforward solution.

Comment: @AMC updated with some of the data.